# How can I use multiple arrayBuffers in a blob?

Tags: javascript, pdf, blob, buffer, arraybuffer

I've been looking all over and haven't found an answer that works. I have multiple arrayBuffers that I would like to combine into one blob. Do I need to combine the arrayBuffers somehow? Or should I create multiple blobs and combine those? Below is an example of what I'm trying to do, but failing

```
const buffers = []

for(var i in files){
    ...code to retrieve arrayBuffer
    buffers.push(arrayBuffer)
}

const blob = new Blob([buffers], {type:'application/pdf'})
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
window.open(url)
```

The above code doesn't work because new Blob expects an arrayBuffer and not an array of them. Is there something that would make this work?

Answer (score 3):

> new Blob expects an arrayBuffer and not an array of them.

No, the Blob constructor awaits a [*blobParts sequence*](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-blobParts). The specs use the term "sequence" as it accepts a few kinds of *ArrayLike* objects, but the core idea is that your code is actually the correct way, since the only parameter will get iterated in search of objects that do correspond to *blobParts*, i.e Blobs, ArrayBuffers, or DOMStrings.

So to answer the question, to concatenate multiple ArrayBuffers into a single Blob, you just have to pass these in the Array you give to the constructor.

```js
const arr1 = new Uint8Array(12);
const buf1 = arr1.buffer;
arr1.fill(0xAA);
const arr2 = new Uint8Array(12);
const buf2 = arr2.buffer;
arr2.fill(0xBB);
const arr3 = new Uint8Array(12);
const buf3 = arr3.buffer;
arr3.fill(0xCC);

const blob = new Blob( [ buf1, buf2, buf3 ] );

new Response( blob ).arrayBuffer().then( buf => {
  const view = new Uint8Array( buf );
  const as_string = [ ...view ].map( (num) => num.toString( 16 ) );
  console.log( as_string );
} );
```

---

To your issue, it lies somewhere else...